# Программа работает,но не корректно

Tags: python

```
amount = input('Количество:')
for i in range(12,19):
    age = int(input('Возраст:'))
if age < 14:
        print('Недостаточный возраст')
```

Программа считывает количество участников и возраст каждого из них. Если возраст кого-то меньше 14 лет, программа печатает «Недостаточный возраст».

Comment: а вопрос в чем? что именно работает не корректно?

Comment: Программа делает совсем не то, что вы написали. Она считывает возраст 7 (именно 7, не больше и не меньше) человек и проверяет возраст последнего из них.

Comment: Вопрос в том, что программа должна не просто принимать возраст, а если он меньше 14 , то программа печатает «Недостаточный возраст».

Comment: Эникейщик, что Вы имеете ввиду?

Comment: Программа получает 7 возраст(от 12 до 19), и проверяет их.

Comment: я имею в виду именно то. что я написал. Программа семь раз спрашивает возраст, независимо от того, что вы вводите в "количество" и потом выводит "недостаточный возраст", если последнее число было меньше 14.

Comment: Если вы хотите получить конкретную помощь, то в вопросе нужно указать, что программа **должна делать**, и что она **делает на самом деле**. Просто написать "некорректно" или "неправильно" или еще что-нибудь типа того недостаточно, потому что кроме вас тут никто не знает, как корректно и правильно.

Comment: А почему семь раз , вместо n-ного количества?

Comment: а посмотрите на свой код и подумайте. Куда вы вводите количество и где указано, сколько раз спрашивать возраст

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужно поместить проверку возраста в цикл `for`, после запроса возраста. Так как после запроса возраста вы спрашиваете его снова, а предыдущий возраст забывается.
Вот что у вас должно получиться:

```
amount = input('Количество:')
for i in range(12,19):
    age = int(input('Возраст:'))
    if age < 14:
            print('Недостаточный возраст')
```

Comment: У меня к вам просьба впредь обращаться к другим участникам на "вы".

Comment: Спасибо, но у меня получаеться , что программа безконечная

Answer (score 1):

Кроме всего, что уже написали, вы никак не используете введённое кол-во участников. А именно по нему нужно делать цикл:

```
amount = int(input('Количество:'))
for _ in range(amount):
    age = int(input('Возраст:'))
    if age < 14:
            print('Недостаточный возраст')
```

Ваша переменная цикла `i` тоже никак не используется, а в таких случаях рекомендуется называть переменную цикла `_`, чтобы показать, что значение этой переменной нас не интересует, и это не баг, а фича, что оно никак не используется в программе.